# Hex char array to decimal

Tags: java, arrays, function, hex, decimal

I need to write a function that takes char array that represent hex number, and gives back the number as decimal integer.
for example: `7F` as base `16` shows in array as `['7', 'F']` and gives back `127`

I tried doing this, but something isn't working :

```
public static int HexToDec(char arr[]) {

    int counter = arr.length - 1;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        sum = (int) (sum + (Math.pow(16, counter)) * i);
        counter--;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Define "something isn't working" more specifically. If you have errors, include them in your question. If you have unexpected output or behavior, describe it.

Comment: And a hint: you are never accessing `arr` in your method, except its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with this implementation:

- Since `counter` is initialized to `arr.length - 1`, if `i` goes from 0 until `< counter`, it will miss the last value
- But actually things are worse than that, because not only `i` is incremented in every iteration, `counter` is decremented, so in fact `i` will only reach half of the array
- You don't need `Math.pow` at all, you can accumulate the correct sum by iteratively multiplying with 16
- Worst of all, the values in `arr` are not used at all by the function, so you cannot possibly get a correct result

Consider this alternative:

```
public static int hexToDec(char[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : arr) {
        int num;
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
            num = c - '0';
        } else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') {
            num = 10 + (c - 'A');
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid character in input: " + c);
        }
        sum *= 16;
        sum += num;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just this can help you :

```
public int hexToDec(char arr[]) throws NumberFormatException {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(arr), 16);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Error or parsing");
    }
}
```

Input

```
int result = hexToDec(new char[]{'7', 'F'});
```

Output

```
127
```